# Windows pg_dump postgres bug: pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

Using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` on postgres to move a dbs from my local Windows machine to a Linux server seemed so simple:

```
pg_dump --format=c -U user localdbs > file.pg.dump
```

Spits out a file. Then upload:

```
pg_restore -c -d serverdbs -v file.pg.dump
```

> pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive

This works perfectly on Linux to Linux. Changing the filetype makes no difference. Changing the encoding at either end makes no difference. Pulling your hair out makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

It's the `>` operator in the `pg_dump` command. It *looks* like it works on Windows, it spits out a file but that file is not properly encoded. On Linux the same command works flawlessly.

You have to use `-f file.pg.dump` instead when using Windows and then everything works.

Hope this saves someone the nightmare I had figuring this out.